# Does googlebot keep sessions when crawling?

Tags: asp.net, session, googlebot, google-crawlers

When googlebot crawls pages does it have session? For example I am storing some variables on the session and using them in my site's pages. When googlebot crawls these pages will I still have the session-variables? In my `global.asax` I am storing some variables on the session at session start. Will I have any problem with Google bot?

Comment: I believe G-Bot is not aware of your session, or I did not get the question right

Comment: you know each request having session in asp.net . it is being kept with cookie . you can see with firebug ASP.NET_SessionId parameter is kept at every request. what i wonder is when i try to reach my session variable will that cause any problem when google bot crawling. apparently when user is browsing it does not cause any problem because session is being kept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to one of your question is: *yes*, you will have problems with Google bot.

Generally we've encountered two types of issues with google bot:

1. it sometimes does not retain HTTP cookies between requests. Our application relies on custom cookies and the there were plenty of google bot requests caught to carry no cookies at all.
2. it makes long breaks between consecutive requests. For example, it retrieves your page and asks for it's scripts later on.

Both will cause troubles with your session. First - you need a precise ASPNETSessionID cookie to be passed between requests. Googlebot will probably sometimes fail to do that. Second - if there's a long timespan between requests, your session is going to terminate even if the cookie is there.

Comment: how can i be precise that to pass ASP.NET_SessionId ? actually it is not a problem if it creates new one but if it does not carry any session it might cause problems.

Comment: ASP.NET Session ID is passed in a cookie. If GoogleBot does not append correct cookie or the cookie points to an empty (timed-out) session, you just have to be defensive in the code and show an error message rather than the Yellow Screen of Death. There's a chance that some (most?) of GB's request WILL carry the correct cookie and WILL hit the non-empty session. However, I have no idea whether or not you can alter the way the GoogleBot inspects your site.

Comment: i see. very good point. do you have any solution offer for this ? any idea :D

Comment: This answer is wrong. The simple answer is that no, Google bot does not use sessions and it would destroy the quality of Google's search results. Imagine clicking a Google search result for "wonderful widgets" that links to Google bots shopping cart on your website, where it had added 7 wonderful widgets. When *you* request that url, you will not have that session and you will see a completely empty cart, a worthless link. And you'll stop using Google search and start using Bing.

Comment: @ButtleButkus: this answer is correct but you haven't understood what I wrote. You are right, your example is correct but you think of google bot hitting several consecutive **pages**. My answer was about our issues with google bot asking for javascripts, images and csses for a single page it retrieves. We observed that the bot postpones going for page resources so it sometimes doesn't even make sense, resources could be volatile and just not available after such long time. Plus, the answer is 4 years old.

Comment: @WiktorZychla the first thing you say is that Google bot "sometimes does not retain HTTP cookies between requests." Isn't it true that Google bot *never* retains them? As far as waiting for scripts, I don't know about that. I'm sure that it caches scripts rather than downloading them over and over again. In Google webmaster tools, Google warns you that if the bot does not have access to your scripts it may not be able to render the page properly. I would be surprised if it would wait very long to download those scripts!

Answer (score 10):

Googlebot actively tries to avoid sessions and does not support cookies. From [First date with the Googlebot: Headers and compression](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2008/03/first-date-with-googlebot-headers-and.html) (March 2008)

> I usually avoid cookies (so no "Cookie:" header) since I don't want
>   the content affected too much by session-specific info. And, if a
>   server uses a session id in a dynamic URL rather than a cookie, I can
>   usually figure this out, so that I don't end up crawling your same
>   page a million times with a million different session ids.

I imagine most regular search engine bots will be similar in this respect. Google is trying to build an index of unique URLs. The URL is the unique key that identifies a unique page of content. Cookies (and sessions) are not passed when a user clicks a link in the SERPS. Google is primarily indexing pages, not sites.

Answer (score 2):

Generally the answer is no, *however* other crawlers (of which there are plenty) work other ways.

I should note that I have seen an instance of a google crawler for Adwords (not the normal googlebot) which DID present a session cookie.

Comment: It's doubtful that any search engine spider would send cookies. If they do, then avoid those search engines because their results will be garbage.

Answer (score 0):

It's very unlikely, I think. It should create a new session every time it crawls your website.

Comment: you mean for each page request ?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG My bet is that the Google Bot will use the query string to keep track of the same session *while it's crawling your site*; however, once it leaves your site and comes back, will very like do it under a different session. I have difficulties imagining a scenario where maintaining session info would be beneficial for the crawler, and in contrast, I can imagine the technical challenges that it would represent to try an maintain session info.

Comment: @Icarus no, it would be idiotic for it to crawl a *stateful* version of your site when its whole purpose is to present *stateless* links for the world to see. If a bot loads up its cart with 7 wonderful widgets and then presents its current url as a search result for widgets, the search engine's users will just see an empty cart. Do you see?